# Size JavaFX WebView to the minimum size needed by the document body

Tags: java, javascript, webview, javafx

I'm writing a custom dialog in JavaFX for my project. I need a variant but quick mode for showing the dialog content.

I know about controlsFX; actually I'm using it but I want to show the content in a WebView so it will be more controllable.

The problem is about the size of the WebView I want to find the height of the document body and set the size of the WebView to that.

I tried the following javascript hack but before showing the dialog I get 0 for the size and after showing dialog the value is not reliable. Is there a better solution or I should forget about it and try to embed a swing component that supports HTML 3?

```
    WebView vw = new WebView();
    vw.getEngine().loadContent("<p>This is my text</p><b>Another</b><p> This is a paragraph</p><ul><li>First cause</li><li>Second cause></li></ul>");
    vw.setPrefSize(500, 50);
    vw.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            // I see that executeScript doesn't work correctly even when the WebView is loaded
            Integer h = (Integer) vw.getEngine().executeScript("document.body.offsetHeight");
            System.out.println("scriptRES: " + h );
            vw.setPrefSize(400, h);
            vw.setMinSize(400, h);
            vw.setMaxSize(400, h);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automated sizing support of WebView is covered by a feature request in the JavaFX issue tracker:

- [RT-25005 Automatic preferred sizing of WebView](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-25005)

The feature request has currently not been implemented or scheduled for implementation.  You can vote for or comment on the feature request.

There is no work-around that I know of.  Earlier version of WebView seemed to work with the following code `engine.executeScript("document.width")` and `engine.executeScript("document.height")`.  But these commands no longer worked last time I tried them.

Answer (score 0):

Until automatic preferred sizing is implemented, a certain blogmeister has come up with a solution that seems to work (*for now*).

It can be found in its original form on [his website](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2014/09/13/how-to-fit-webview-height-based-on-its-content-in-java-fx-2-2/).

It makes having a preferred-size `WebView` as easy as

```
WebViewFitContent webViewFitContent = new WebViewFitContent(html);
yourContainer.getChildren().add(webViewFitContent);
```

[image: WebViewFitContent in action]

---

In case the link were to ever die,

#### WebViewFitContent.java

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import netscape.javascript.JSException;

import java.util.Set;

public final class WebViewFitContent extends Region {

    final WebView webview = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = webview.getEngine();

    public WebViewFitContent(String content) {
        webview.setPrefHeight(5);

        widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                Double width = (Double)newValue;
                webview.setPrefWidth(width);
                adjustHeight();
            }
        });

        webview.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> arg0, State oldState, State newState)         {
                if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    adjustHeight();
                }
            }
        });

        webview.getChildrenUnmodifiable().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Node>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Node> change) {
                Set<Node> scrolls = webview.lookupAll(".scroll-bar");
                for (Node scroll : scrolls) {
                    scroll.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });

        setContent(content);
        getChildren().add(webview);
    }

    public void setContent(final String content) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                webEngine.loadContent(getHtml(content));
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adjustHeight();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(webview,0,0,w,h,0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }

    private void adjustHeight() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Object result = webEngine.executeScript(
                            "var myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');" +
                                    "if (myDiv != null) myDiv.offsetHeight");
                    if (result instanceof Integer) {
                        Integer i = (Integer) result;
                        double height = new Double(i);
                        height = height + 20;
                        webview.setPrefHeight(height);
                    }
                } catch (JSException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getHtml(String content) {
        return "<html><body>" +
                "<div id=\"mydiv\">" + content + "</div>" +
                "</body></html>";
    }

}
```

Note 1: In the above I added a null-check in the javascript and chose to print out any exceptions that might occur instead of ignoring them.

Note 2: Sometimes the `WebView`'s content doesn't show through. If anyone else experiences this please leave a comment.

Comment: I've tested this code with JDK8u202 and it does not seem to work.

Comment: @Maxoudela, odd. I'm almost certain that I've used it on that JDK. I can confirm that using JDK8u211 it works as I'm using it right now. Here's the [exact code](https://gist.github.com/TurekBot/fa94bd20969dad8ad31bc5d859f7234d) I'm using.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, thanks for the code. It seems to work in a simple case, but I'm trying to use it in a TableView/SpreadsheetView and then it does not seem to work.
Also, I'm trying to make it work with the width using the same technique but apparently it's not working at all..

Comment: The webview's content missing appears to be a long standing bug... https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087569. 
 I've reopened it under an FX support contract in attempt to fix it... https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8237583.  I've asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59803411.  Meanwhile, working hard on a workaround while I'm waiting for the upstream patch.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very late answer.

You have to apply ChangeListener on the document, before calulating the height. 
Kindly find a running example to your question at: [Correct sizing of Webview embedded in Tabelcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856471/correct-sizing-of-webview-embedded-in-tabelcell/42922745#42922745)

However my experience is that the high is still sometimes to big.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question then [vote to close](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If the question is not a duplicate then tailor the answer to this specific question.

Comment: I had the same question and could not find an solution here. Later I have combined the information which I have found here with a information from other question.  I was getting further, but new issues poped up. So I was asking my new question, which i have linked here. So the solution to my question should also anser the question here. More details can be found at the link I have proveded.  I'm not sure how to handle this conform to the SE rules. Which question shall be closed (The orginal one or my extended duplicate with active bounty and a working solution)?